# How to configure standard Files to work with samba shared folder with authentication

Tags: networking, samba

My ubuntu version is 18.04. And I have the shared windows folders with specific workgroup and authetification. Let it be for example `workgroup=MyCompany` and `user=MyCompanyUser` and some password. I know how to connect via `smbclient`, I can set these parameters in arguments and it works properly.

Does anyone know how to configure standard ubuntu application **Files** to work such way.At this moment i see:

> Failed to retrieve share list from server: Connection timeout

Answer (score 0):

I found that it works out of the box. My issue was in incorrect uri. Files shows dialog with authentication.